# Adding field values using apex:variable under apex:pageblockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, salesforce1-app

I am adding the field value i.e number type  with the apex:variable but getting the error

> Incorrect parameter type for operator '+'. Expected Text, received Number

Comment: From the docs,

https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_variable.htm

The attribute "Var" is of type "String" always.

I could see the same in editor also.

![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb6Xa.jpg

Comment: Actually I'm using this concept in the below link.. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22386/how-to-calculate-the-row-values-in-apexrepeat/74014#74014   this code is working accurately as adding the field values

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a very similar to piece of code to yours to work - but I found that I couldn't even compile the page using `outputField` - You should only use `outputField` for values that are directly tied to a sObject value.

Change to `outputText` and also verify that `wrapRec.T_Price__c` is in fact a number value.

Failing that, try wrapping the value to be added in a `VALUE()` function.

**EDIT** Here is the code I used. I used a list of accounts in the controller.

```
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" collapsible="false" >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acctWrapper}" var="acct">
            <apex:column value="{!acct.acctId}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!acct.name}"/>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:variable var="total1" value="{!total1 + acct.num}" />
                <apex:outputText value="{!total1}" />
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:variable var="total2" value="{!total2 + acct.num}" />
                <apex:outputText value="{!total2}" />
            </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Here is the wrapper code:

```
public class Wrapper {
    public String name {get; set;}
    public Id acctId {get; set;}
    public Integer num {get; set;}


    public Wrapper(String name, Id acctId, Integer num) {
      this.name = name;
      this.acctId = acctId;
      this.num = num;
    }
}
```

And here is where I build the wrapper list:

```
//defined at top of class
public Wrapper[] acctWrapper {get; set;}


accounts = [SELECT Name, Id From Account LIMIT 20];
acctWrapper = new Wrapper[]{};
Integer count = 0;
for (Account a : accounts){
    acctWrapper.add(new Wrapper(a.Name, a.Id, count));
    count+=1;
}
```

Comment: "T_Price__c' is number type.   Can you explain with example code?

Comment: Updated - try now

Comment: Actually,I am adding the field value to the total that's not working for the custom object field. It is showing me the error message when i add the total1 and the field in value attribute.My wrapper class have getter and setters. I want to do exactly total like this example...   [link] (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20563/to-achieve-grand-total-for-the-retrieved-column-in-a-datatable-generated-using-s)

Comment: Updated again - try this one. This uses a wrapper class and I'm adding a number from the wrapper class to the `apex:variable` - no errors.

Comment: i am using custom object field i.e number type instead of count variable.It's not working.

Comment: Can you try using a count variable to see if it works? Perhaps try recreating my code as closely as possible and see if it works.