# How to develop the Matrix report in Visuafore page

Tags: apex, visualforce, reporting, jquery, custom

Can we achieve the below by using VF page or some external jQuery widget. 
[image]

I have tried with Gant or dxhtml queries. but no works.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to use jQuery?

It's much simpler to use standard Visualforce components. The key ones for your requirements will be:

- [apex:pageBlockTable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm)
- [apex:column](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_column.htm)
- [apex:facet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_facet.htm)

You can populate the table with standard sObjects or create your own Apex objects as needed.

Comment: How to make summary for the row wise and column wise?

Comment: Calculate the totals in your Apex controller / extension and then place them in the table.

Comment: Is this possible for each and every row. Can you make any sample please?

Comment: How were you planning on summarising your data for use with the jQuery data?

Comment: Also there are some code samples in this thread http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22386/how-to-calculate-the-row-values-in-apexrepeat

Comment: Easily done with SOQL date filters.

Comment: I don't, but there are loads of blog posts etc. showing how to use these components. I'd suggest reading up on them a little bit, giving them a try and then raise a new question if you get stuck again.